# how to generate new dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"p1" : [2,3,5], "p2" : [2,3,5], "s1": [10,20,30], "s2": [5,-2, 7]})
df
```

[image]

I want to get a new data frame, let's say df_new. df_new will have the same column labels as the df. the values of p1 and p2 for both dataframes will be the same, but for df_new the column values s1 and s2 will be produced with the formula below from df:

s1 = (s1 * p1 / p2) and s2 = (s2 * p1 / p2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) with [`Series.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.div.html):

```
df[['s1','s2']] = df[['s1','s2']].mul(df.p1.div(df.p2), axis=0)

print (df)
   p1  p2    s1   s2
0   2   2  10.0  5.0
1   3   3  20.0 -2.0
2   5   5  30.0  7.0
```

EDIT: One idea is use [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) with `s` substring

```
cols = df.filter(like='s').columns
#or if starts columns names by s
#cols = df.filter(regex='^s').columns
df[cols] = df[cols].mul(df.p1.div(df.p2), axis=0)
```

Or select last N  columns, e.g. here 2 by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df.iloc[:, -2:] = df.iloc[:, -2:].mul(df.p1 / df.p2, axis=0)
```

---

Use [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
df = df.assign(s1 = (df.s1 * df.p1 / df.p2),
               s2 = (df.s2 * df.p1 / df.p2))
print (df)

   p1  p2    s1   s2
0   2   2  10.0  5.0
1   3   3  20.0 -2.0
2   5   5  30.0  7.0
```

Or create new columns like:

```
df.s1 = (df.s1 * df.p1 / df.p2) 
df.s2 = (df.s2 * df.p1 / df.p2) 
print (df)
   p1  p2    s1   s2
0   2   2  10.0  5.0
1   3   3  20.0 -2.0
2   5   5  30.0  7.0
```

Comment: What if i had 50 columns from s1 to s50? is there any shortcut?

Comment: @burhancigdem - yes, added `EDIT` to answer.

Comment: df.iloc[:, -2:] = df.iloc[:, -2:].mul(df.p1 / df.p2, axis=0) works instead of df.iloc[:, -2:] = df.iloc[:, -2:].div(df.p1 / df.p2, axis=0). Thanks.